# Can I change properties of arbitrarily nested details tags in pure HTML/CSS without manually specifying every possible level of nesting?

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a page that displays nested comments, which may be arbitrary levels deep. To support expanding/collapsing comments, I'm using the HTML5 `<details>` and `<summary>` tags. Right now, I'm using the following CSS/HTML code to add a red border to top-level comments, a blue border to second-from-top-level comments, green on third, etc. Unfortunately, I don't necessarily know in advance how many levels deep the comment chain will be.

Is there a way to specify a list of colors and have CSS programmatically run through the colors for each level of nested tag? **Without any Javascript?** Instead of specifying

```
details
details>details
details>details>details
```

up to some arbitrary limit of, say, ten comments deep and hope that there won't be more than that? (I know that ten nested comments on a narrow page doesn't look, but unfortunately that's the potential "input data" I'm stuck with, so to speak).

```css
details>* {
  margin-left: 1em;
}

details {
  border-left: 5px solid red;
}

details>details {
  border-left: 5px solid blue;
}

details>details>details {
  border-left: 5px solid green;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <details open="open">
    <summary>Title for comment #1</summary>
    <p>Comment 1: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis
      aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
    <details open="open">
      <summary>Title for comment #2</summary>
      <p>Comment 2: Curabitur pretium tincidunt lacus. Nulla gravida orci a odio. Nullam varius, turpis et commodo pharetra.</p>
      <details open="open">
        <summary>Title for comment #3</summary>
        <p>Comment 3: Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium.</p>
      </details>
    </details>
  </details>
  <details open="open">
    <summary>Title for comment #4</summary>
    <p>Comment 4: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis
      aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
    <details open="open">
      <summary>Title for comment #5</summary>
      <p>Comment 5: Curabitur pretium tincidunt lacus. Nulla gravida orci a odio. Nullam varius, turpis et commodo pharetra.</p>
      <details open="open">
        <summary>Title for comment #6</summary>
        <p>Comment 6: Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium.</p>
      </details>
    </details>
  </details>
</body>
```

Comment: " have CSS programmatically" .... there is no programmatically in CSS. It is purely declarative.

Comment: The better question is what you **want** the intended functionality to look like. You have three example colours, sure ...but what should the 7th colour be? The 8th? Are you detracting a value from an RGB scale? If so, you *may* be able to make use of a combination of `calc()` and CSS variables ...but it's impossible to know what your criteria would be for each 'step'; there doesn't seem to be a clear 'pattern' for your logic to follow as it progresses down the hierarchy. Even then, `section > section > section > section` is perfectly fine, and increases the specificity.

Comment: @ObsidianAge Thanks, that's a good point. I guess I had in my head an arbitrary list of, say, 10 colors, and those would be used in order and recycled. If I wanted to use the `calc()` function to follow some pattern, e.g. various shades of red on an RGB scale, how would I do that in this case? I'm mostly agnostic to the colors themselves.

Comment: @JonP Thanks, you're right. CSS isn't programmatic. I had in mind something like the `nth-child()` selectors. I guess that's what I meant.

Comment: I get what you're going for... I just don't think there's much you can cut down here. Like, you would still have to declare what each of the ten colours are, and then you'd still end up with just as many lines of CSS, unless you can 'subtract' / 'add' those colours somehow. Which, for the record, [**can be done**](https://css-tricks.com/css-variables-calc-rgb-enforcing-high-contrast-colors/) using `calc()`, albeit in a lot of (confusing) lines of code. Also, keep in mind that `:nth-child()` works on *siblings*, not children :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS is purely declarative. There is no notions of arrays or similar. You can simplify what you have a little by overriding the only thing that changes, the color.

```css
details>* {
  margin-left: 1em;
}

details {
  border-left: 5px solid red;
}

details>details {
  border-color: blue;
}

details>details>details {
  border-color: green;
}

details>details>details>details {
  border-color: yellow;
}

details>details>details>details>details {
  border-color: goldenrod;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <details open="open">
    <summary>Title for comment #1</summary>
    <p>Comment 1: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis
      aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
    <details open="open">
      <summary>Title for comment #2</summary>
      <p>Comment 2: Curabitur pretium tincidunt lacus. Nulla gravida orci a odio. Nullam varius, turpis et commodo pharetra.</p>
      <details open="open">
        <summary>Title for comment #3</summary>
        <p>Comment 3: Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium.</p>
      </details>
    </details>
  </details>
  <details open="open">
    <summary>Title for comment #4</summary>
    <p>Comment 4: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis
      aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
    <details open="open">
      <summary>Title for comment #5</summary>
      <p>Comment 5: Curabitur pretium tincidunt lacus. Nulla gravida orci a odio. Nullam varius, turpis et commodo pharetra.</p>
      <details open="open">
        <summary>Title for comment #6</summary>
        <p>Comment 6: Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium.</p>
      </details>
    </details>
  </details>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you can adjust your HTML by adding an extra wrapper you can do it using some CSS variables trick and `linear-gradient`.

The idea is to define a gradient with the colors you want and this will be your array (I considered 4 colors here). Then you use the `background-position` to show the next color using a CSS variable that you increment at each level (that's why we need the extra wrapper).

```css
:root {
  --p: 0; /* Control the first color*/
}

details {
  padding-left: 5px;
  position: relative; /* Make the pseudo element relative to details to replace the border */
  --x: var(--p);
}

div {
  --p: calc(var(--x) + 1); /* Increment the variable for the next level*/
}

details>div:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 5px;
  background: 
   linear-gradient(to right, 
    /* Your array of colors (N = 4) */
    red    calc(0*100%/4) calc(1*100%/4), 
    blue   calc(1*100%/4) calc(2*100%/4), 
    green  calc(2*100%/4) calc(3*100%/4), 
    yellow calc(3*100%/4) calc(4*100%/4)) 
    /* Position: x*(100%/(N-1)) 0   Size: N*100% 100%  */
   calc(var(--x)*100%/3) 0/400% 100%;
}


details>* {
  margin-left: 1em;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <details open="open">
    <summary>Title for comment #1</summary>
    <div>
      <p>Comment 1: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor 
        aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
      <details open="open">
        <summary>Title for comment #2</summary>
        <div>
          <p>Comment 2: Curabitur pretium tincidunt lacus. Nulla gravida orci a odio. Nullam varius, turpis et commodo pharetra.</p>
          <details open="open">
            <summary>Title for comment #3</summary>
            <div>
              <p>Comment 3: Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium.</p>
            </div>
          </details>
        </div>
      </details>
    </div>
  </details>
 
  <details open="open">
    <summary>Title for comment #4</summary>
    <div>
      <p>Comment 4: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis
        aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
      <details open="open">
        <summary>Title for comment #5</summary>
        <div>
          <p>Comment 5: Curabitur pretium tincidunt lacus. Nulla gravida orci a odio. Nullam varius, turpis et commodo pharetra.</p>
          <details open="open">
            <summary>Title for comment #6</summary>
            <div>
              <p>Comment 6: Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium.</p>
              <details open="open">
                <summary>Title for comment #6</summary>
                <div>
                  <p>Comment 6: Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium.</p>
                  <details open="open">
                    <summary>Title for comment #6</summary>
                    <div>
                      <p>Comment 6: Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium.</p>
                    </div>
                  </details>
                </div>
              </details>
            </div>
          </details>
        </div>
      </details>
    </div>
  </details>
</body>
```

You can consider the same idea and generate colors based on an initial one using filter, hsl or any other technique:

```css
:root {
  --p: 0; /* Control the first color*/
}

details {
  padding-left: 5px;
  position: relative; /* Make the pseudo element relative to details to replace the border */
  --x: var(--p);
}

div {
  --p: calc(var(--x) + 2); /* Increment the variable for the next level*/
}

details>div:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 5px;
  background: red;
  filter:hue-rotate(calc(var(--x)*45deg)) brightness(2);
}


details>* {
  margin-left: 1em;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <details open="open">
    <summary>Title for comment #1</summary>
    <div>
      <p>Comment 1: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor 
        aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
      <details open="open">
        <summary>Title for comment #2</summary>
        <div>
          <p>Comment 2: Curabitur pretium tincidunt lacus. Nulla gravida orci a odio. Nullam varius, turpis et commodo pharetra.</p>
          <details open="open">
            <summary>Title for comment #3</summary>
            <div>
              <p>Comment 3: Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium.</p>
            </div>
          </details>
        </div>
      </details>
    </div>
  </details>
 
  <details open="open">
    <summary>Title for comment #4</summary>
    <div>
      <p>Comment 4: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis
        aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
      <details open="open">
        <summary>Title for comment #5</summary>
        <div>
          <p>Comment 5: Curabitur pretium tincidunt lacus. Nulla gravida orci a odio. Nullam varius, turpis et commodo pharetra.</p>
          <details open="open">
            <summary>Title for comment #6</summary>
            <div>
              <p>Comment 6: Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium.</p>
              <details open="open">
                <summary>Title for comment #6</summary>
                <div>
                  <p>Comment 6: Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium.</p>
                  <details open="open">
                    <summary>Title for comment #6</summary>
                    <div>
                      <p>Comment 6: Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium.</p>
                    </div>
                  </details>
                </div>
              </details>
            </div>
          </details>
        </div>
      </details>
    </div>
  </details>
</body>
```